# how can i use local String value in another method

Tags: java, android

i have passed data from recyclerview mainactivity to exoplayer activity through intent.now problem is i want use that value in another method. so how can i use that value in another method.

exoplayer activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exoplayer);

        thumb = findViewById(R.id.thumb);
        head = findViewById(R.id.head);

        String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");

        //i want use this String value in different method
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

        head.setText(title);
        Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(image).into(thumb);

        initializeplayer();
    }

    //i want use that string value in this method.
    public void initializeplayer(){

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.exo);
        simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);

        DataSource.Factory datasourcefactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "appname"));

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(datasourcefactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url1));
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
```

Comment: You can call `getIntent().getStringExtra("url");` in every method!!

Comment: Which value do you want to use in another method? please share  more details on the same

Comment: @Omid.N Thank you dude

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- Declare `image`, `title` and `url` outside the `onCreate()` like this:

```
String image;
String title;
String url;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exoplayer);

        thumb = findViewById(R.id.thumb);
        head = findViewById(R.id.head);

        image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
        title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");

        //i want use this String value in different method
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

        head.setText(title);
        Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(image).into(thumb);

        initializeplayer();
    }

    //i want use that string value in this method.
    public void initializeplayer(){

        //use image, title and url 

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.exo);
        simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);

        DataSource.Factory datasourcefactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "appname"));

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(datasourcefactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url1));
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
```

- Pass `image`, `title` and `url` as arguments of `initializeplayer` like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exoplayer);

        thumb = findViewById(R.id.thumb);
        head = findViewById(R.id.head);

        String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");

        //i want use this String value in different method
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

        head.setText(title);
        Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(image).into(thumb);

        initializeplayer(image, title, url);
    }

    //i want use that string value in this method.
    public void initializeplayer(String image, String title, String url){

        //use image, title and url 

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.exo);
        simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);

        DataSource.Factory datasourcefactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "appname"));

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(datasourcefactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url1));
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make these variables **global** and use it in any function you don't need to pass it again and again.

```
public String image;
public String title;
public String url;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exoplayer);

---add your code---
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass that value while calling the method as

```
initializeplayer(url);
```

And make few changes in the method declaration as

```
public void initializeplayer(String url){
    //access url in this method
}
```

I don't see any reason why you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add parameters into your method. For example: `public void initializeplayer(String arg){}`